# Regular Expression not matching data but Regular Expression confirmed working

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java program that grabs a date-time String and have tested in multiple regular expression test sites to check if they do indeed work, which they do.

```
private static final Pattern MATCH_DATE_TIME = Pattern.compile("<span id=\"lblMatchTime\" style=\"padding: 0px;\">([\\d+/ GMT:]+)</span>");
```

The unescaped version of the expression

```
<span id="lblMatchTime" style="padding: 0px;">([\d/ :GMT]+)</span>
```

and the websites I tested the above on.

- [regexerV1](http://www.regexr.com/v1/)
- [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

With the following data

```
                    <div style="width: 30%; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">                             <span>                                 Time  :                             </span>                             <span id="lblMatchTime" style="padding: 0px;">05/28/2014 14:16:21 GMT</span>                         </div>                         <div style="width: 30%; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">                             <span>duration:                             </span>                             <span id="lblMatchDuration" style="padding: 0px;">50</span>                             <span>                                 minutes                             </span>                         </div>                     </div>
```

Both of the above websites with the unescaped versions correctly match the intended data below

```
<span id="lblMatchTime" style="padding: 0px;">05/28/2014 14:16:21 GMT</span>  //the matched data
05/28/2014 14:16:21 GMT //$1 extracted data
```

although both the above sites successfully match and extract the data my program does not.

Here is the code for my program (minimum code example)

```
private static final Pattern MATCH_DATE_TIME = Pattern.compile("<span id=\"lblMatchTime\" style=\"padding: 0px;\">([\\d+/ GMT:]+)</span>");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {

        String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter The Match ID", "Grab Match Details", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        Matcher m = MATCH_DATE_TIME.matcher(data);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
        String dateTime = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ise)
    {
        ise.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `m.matches()` do?

Comment: if Matcher.matches() returns true then there is available data that can be gained from using Matcher.group()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()

Comment: Just FYI, your `[\d/ :GMT]+` should be `[\d/ :]+GMT`.  Your regex works, but not for the reason you think.  I'll leave the explanation as an exercise for the student. :P

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use `Matcher#find()` instead of `Matcher#matches()`. `find()` searches the given string for a match while `matches()` attempts to match the entire string. Your regex does not match the entire string.

Comment: This indirectly fixes my problem

Comment: Indirectly?  This was *exactly* the problem: using `matches()` when you should have been using `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern MATCH_DATE_TIME = Pattern.compile("<span id=\"lblMatchTime\" style=\"padding: 0px;\">([\\d+/ GMT:]+)</span>");

    public static void test()
    {
        try
        {

            String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter The Match ID", "Grab Match Details", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            Matcher m = MATCH_DATE_TIME.matcher(data);
            if(m.find())
            {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ise)
        {
            ise.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sotirios is correct, however as an alternative, in cases like this I prefer a one-line solution *not* involving the clumsy `Matcher` api, but using `replaceAll()` instead:

```
String dateTime = input.replaceAll(".*(?:<span id=\"lblMatchTime\" style=\"padding: 0px;\">([\\d+/ GMT:]+)</span>)?.*", "$1");
```

This works by adding `".*"` to either end of the pattern so the entire input is matched, then replacing it with the captured target using a back-reference `$1` in the replacement to group 1. There's added regex special sauce of the entire expression wrapped in an optional non-capturing group to make the result blank if there's no match.

This avoids several lines of code, and bypasses tests for matching or not.